# Alteration in a stave in a score: does it communicate with the other stave?

Tags: theory, piano, accidentals

I have a question about [Imperial March, arranged by Nicola Morali](http://www.nicolamorali.com/the-imperial-march-star-wars-per-pianoforte/).

In the measure 10, on the left hand, is the "G" note really without a ♯?
(Since the left hand and the right hand don't align according to academic music rules.)

Or should the score have actually a ♯ for the G note (note number 8) of the left hand, at this measure?

Remark: the right hand is using a treble clef (G clef) for this measure number, while the left hand is using a bass clef (F clef) for this measure number.

[image]

Comment: The note doesn't appear to be a B, I think it's a G, if it's l.h. and bass clef.  You do mean the penultimate note at the bottom in that bar?

Comment: Apologizes I'm a french. I translated incorrectly. This is a G. I correct the question now

Comment: translation of cle de Sol isn‘t G key, but treble clef, clef de Fa = bass clef ( not F key).

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli *clé de sol* and *clé de fa* translate more literally as "G clef" and "F clef," respectively.  In modern usage, they are only used for treble and bass clef, but in earlier times they were movable (as the C clef continues to be).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, that looks like a typo in the sheet (or someone who thinks accidentals apply to all notes in the score, independent of the octave/staff). You should play a G♯; that will make the left hand play a D♭5 chord, which is consistent with other arrangements I have checked, which have a D♭m or equivalently a C♯m chord there; the 'minor' is implied by the F♭/E in the melody.

Instead of a G♯, it's also possible to write it as an A♭. Looking at the other left-hand notes in that measure, which are written as D♭s, I'd argue that it's even more logical; however, the right hand does use a G♯, and an E instead of an F♭. That's not really consistent, and in general, this is not positive indicator for the quality of the scoresheet.

Answer (score 14):

There are many other mistakes in this transcription. I wouldn’t use it! Db  should be C# and then the 5th would be G#.

Google for *imperial march* (images)

Compare with these music sheets: [image]

Comment: +1 for "I wouldn't use it," which is the most practically useful response to this question.

Comment: The base line on this transcription seems a bit simpler, lacking that drumroll-like triplet.  Some combination of the two might sound more interesting.  (Ultimately, transcribing any full orchestral piece to solo piano, you're going to lose some elements no matter what you do, but it's nice to try and get a bit more of the original feel into it if you can.)